# Logging in a website via vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to login to Facebook using [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) code from my Excel as follows:

```
 Sub CallChrome()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate ("https://www.fb.com")
        Do
            If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
                ie.Visible = False
                Exit Do
            Else
                DoEvents
            End If
        Loop
        ie.Document.Forms(0).all("Username").Value = "username"
        ie.Document.Forms(0).all("Password").Value = "password"
        ie.Document.Forms(0).submit

    End Sub
```

However, it shows an error "Object Required error 424" , on the `ie.Document.Forms(0)`...... 
Although the login page is being displayed, I am not able to pass my credentials.

Comment: Why is there ```` after the password line? Why is it called `CallChrome` and then calling `InternetExplorer.application`? You seem to have taken the code from [this page](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/461524-visual-basic-applications-open-website-logon-username-password.html) but copied and pasted wrong. Did you try the other answers there e.g. `With .document`   `.items("username")="brazenmore"` ? Even better you could adapt this to Facebook `Document.getElementById("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_UserName").Focus` Then enter the relevant information (password or name)

Comment: Yes , I tried , same error!

Comment: For both solutions? Did you modify `Document.getElementById("Template_GLE_Login_LoginView1_login_UserName").Focus` correctly and try that?

Comment: and I need a general login , not facebook specific

Comment: But not all sites use the same wording or naming conventions for 'User Name' and 'Password' and then there's other languages, I'll have to defer this to someone else to see if it is possible.

Comment: okay , thanks! I tried this : ie.Document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "myusername"
ie.Document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "mypass"  .It didn't give me any error this time , but said , invalid credentials , I am pretty sure my credentials are right, tried loging in normally with them and they worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. I replaced this:

```
    ie.Document.Forms(0).all("Username").Value = "username"
    ie.Document.Forms(0).all("Password").Value = "password"
```

with this:

```
    ie.Document.all.Item("email").Value = "username"
    ie.Document.all.Item("pass").Value = "password"
```