# Error 424 In VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create the Automation using VB to log in to website by using the User ID & Password, but its giving me error 424 Object required as shown below the VB Code

```
Sub Test()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("https://appsglobal.nike.com/Citrix/AppsGlobal/auth/login.aspx" & ActiveCell)
    Do
        If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
            IE.Visible = False
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    IE.Document.Forms(0).all("User Name").Value = "UserID"
    IE.Document.Forms(0).all("Password").Value = "Password"
    IE.Document.Forms(0).submit

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Are you dealing with VB or VBA? Is Activecell set? Have you checked the content of it? Have you tried to use a constant as Webpage to narrow down your problem?

Comment: This Line - IE.Document.Forms(0).all("User Name").Value = "UserID" is throwing error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging in a website via vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524265/logging-in-a-website-via-vba)